# Javascript to determination the device type IOS or Android and sho div depend on that

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, iphone

below is my code what i need to do is if the mobile androd show ANDROID_USERS div if iphone show IOS_USERS div ONE TIME ONLY "first visit" every thing working on the right way but when i use this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf

its not check the mobile type in right way
i need to know if i check the mobile type in right way ?

```
    <head>
    <style>
            #IOS_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

            #ANDROID_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

    </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//check mobile type
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }

};

            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            }


            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i].trim();
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }

            function MarkVisited() {
                setCookie("visited", "visited", 10)
            }

            function ClearCookie(cname) {
                setCookie(cname, "", 1)
            }



            $(document).ready(function() {

                 if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.iOS()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').hide();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').show();
                }
                else if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.Android()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').show();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').hide();
                }
                MarkVisited();
            });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="IOS_USERS">
         IOS 
        </div>
        <div id="ANDROID_USERS">
         ANDROID 
        </div>
        <button id="ClearCookie" onClick="ClearCookie('visited')">Clear Cookie</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have separate css for for Android and Iphone based on the device os you can load the css this is best way to handle it. 
[Detect device and swap the CSS file - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954196/detect-device-and-swap-the-css-file-jquery)

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: i want to test my code ton know if its work well or not ? in something online

Comment: Add user agent to your browser and check it. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf

Comment: please check my question i update it but still check the mobile on worng way

Comment: please check my question